# Sharepoint2010 Lists Lookup

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I'm creating 3 lists using Sharepoint 2010 UI.
The lists and relationship are as follows:
Training (parent) -> Training Instance (child, look up Training ) -> Training Session (grandchild,lookup Training Instance)

The problem is when I try to look up the Training Instance from the Training Session list, the Training(look up field) is not visible. All other fields except for the lookup field in the Training Instance lists is visible in the Training Session.

Is it not possible to go beyond child list.
Is there any way that I could achieve the same thing (parent -> child -> grandchild).

Any help is very much apperciated.
Thanks.

I think it would be much clearer if you guys tried to create the lists in your development machine. I'm using custom list to define the three lists I'm using. I would suggest you to create the following lists:-

Training <-lookup <- Training Instance <- lookup <- Training Session.

All the lists have one similiar field named Training. This field is first created in the training list, the Training Instance is created when a user select which training he wants to held. And because the training instance can have more than one session, the Training session will keep the lists.

You'll see that you can add items to the Training Session just fine, but when you try to insert item for Training Session, you'll find that the training field in this lists which is set to look up the Training Instance is empty.

I hope I made my problem clear.
Thanks to all you guys for trying to help me, I really2 apperciate it.
Thanks.

Comment: Why ask on two sites? At least direct to the other. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12782/sharepoint2010-lists-lookup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that with SharePoint 2010 OOB. You have to either use Foundation API or REST API to display ALL the three lists info in one list-LIKE format. Using a control like hierarchical grid would be ideal in this scenario.

You should create a separate list for look ups or lists with one to many / many to many relationships.If you have a one to one relationship  between your training instance and training session lists then I suggest moving your training session fields to training instance list and make it in ONE list.

EDIT:
Look up Field/Column settings should look like this
[image: List settings should look like this]

Comment: Hi Ken, if only the relationship between the training instance and training session is 1 to 1. But it is'nt. :( The requirement stated that for one training instance there can be more than one training session. Just to be more specific, the problem is when I try to insert a training session using the training session list via the built in form (by clicking the add new item link), the training field in the training session lists which is a look up field(target is Training Instance) does not contain any value.

Comment: Your Training Instance list must contain at least one list item for you to be able to select in the drop down look up field of training session list. Make sure your training instance list is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

Just as on the other site. There are a lot of ways of doing this.

Web Services is one with SOAP and CAML. The other is SPServices. You will find plenty of examples of both on here and on the web.

Elaborate on which language you are using and maybe include more details so we can help more.

[Lists web services - GetListItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlistitems%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

[SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices)

Comment: Thank you very much, I really2 apperciate that you try to answer in both of the forums. I really2 need some assistance from you guys out there. I'm still new in sharepoint development (2 months). The problem is when I try to insert a training session using the training session list via the built in form (by clicking the add new item link), the training field in the training session list which is a look up field(target is Training Instance) does not contain any value.

Comment: Im about a month into SharePoint myself. It sounds like you are using custom lists and without more information, im not sure what you are trying to achieve. You should edit your question and add more information. The lookup column is just so the user has options when adding a new item to the list. The calculated column actually references other data and can make computations for the value.

Comment: I've edited my question to add more ingormation as you suggested, please have a look. Thanks